# How do I generalize the return type of spring controllers such that if the users are present it returns the list of users else it returns a string?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, backend, http-status-code-404

```
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllUsers(){

        List<User> users = this.userRepository.findAll();

        if(users.isEmpty()){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body("Content unavailable!");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(users);

    }
```

Please let me know! Since the "Content unavailable does not get displayed.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Having an endpoint that returns wildly different responses does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: @Turing85 Thats the requirement, you know how to generalize it?

Comment: Well the content does not get displaye becaused you set `NO_CONTENT` as response status. A `NO_CONTENT`response has... no content (i.e. no body). A `404 NOT FOUND`, `409 CONFLICT` or `410 GONE` seems more fitting.

Comment: If that's "the requirement", it's a requirement to produce a very bad API.  How is the caller supposed to handle a result that may or may not be a list of users?

Comment: @Turing85 thanks a lot man! It helped, I din't know if status code is validated as well!

Comment: @accessviolation agreed, but this is just for demonstration in a backend test

Comment: A wise man once said "*Nothing lasts longer than a temporary*"...